# Loop with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using React, I am implementing [Dexie.js](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/wiki/Getting-started) for this example. However, I don't believe this to be particularly important. I would like to know how to execute a loop of the objects in my IndexDB database using React.

As shown in my code below, `dayta` holds my database, and stores `friends` with `name` and `age` values. When my function `carveit` is run, it takes what users have typed in and places that value on `{this.state.etv}`. The code works.

However, I do not know how to have `{this.state.etv}` show ALL entries. As is, it only shows the most recent addition. I understand I would have to execute some kind of loop, and use the `map` function, but I am unsure how to go about that.

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return { etv:'' }    
    },

    carveit:function(){
        var enteringtitle = document.getElementById('entertitle').value;
        var enteringmessage = document.getElementById('enterentry').value;    


        var dayta = new Dexie('testcase');
        dayta.version(1).stores({
            friends:'name, age'    
        });   


        dayta.open().catch(function(error){
        alert("Oh no son: " +error);    
        });

        dayta.friends.add({
            name: enteringtitle,
            age: enteringmessage    
        });    

        dayta.friends.each((friend)=>{
            this.setState({etv: friend.name}); 
        });    

    },    

    functionrun:function(){
        return (<div>
            <ul>
                <li>{this.state.etv}</li>   
            </ul>        
            <p>Entry Title</p>    
            <input id="entertitle" type="text" className="form-control"/>

            <p>Your Entry</p>    
            <textarea id="enterentry" className="form-control"></textarea>


            <input id="entrytitle" type="submit" value="Publish" onClick={this.carveit} />        
        </div>);
    },    

    render:function(){
        if (this.props.contentadd){
            return this.functionrun();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }    
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the loop separately and have it return jsx. You can then use the return value in your template since arrays of jsx partials are supported.

```
render: function() {
    var itemElements = this.state.items.map(function(item, i) {
        return (
            <li>{item}</li>
        );
    });

    return (
        <ul>
            {itemElements}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey. I get `this.state.etv.map is not a function` error when following your structure.

Comment: Right, if `this.state.etv` isn't an array, then it won't have a `map()` function. Your state variable needs to be an array in order to loop over it. I'll make my example more generic so that isn't misleading.

Comment: So I added a `getInitialState` of `etv:[{name: ' ', age: ' ' }]` so that it is an array. But I still get `this.state.etv.map is not a function`.  In addition, I added `var itemElements = this.state.etv.map(function(item, i){ return (li key={i}>{item.name}</li);});`

Comment: You should `console.log(this.state.etv)` and see what value it has and `console.log(typeof this.state.etv)` to see what type it is. For all you know your state may not be set up correctly.